# Delphi Как заполняется многомерный массив

Tags: delphi, массивы

Не пойму, как заполняется многомерный массив **mkts** , последовательно ? На входе бинарный файл.

```
mkts = array [0..3, 1..6, 1..16] of SmallInt;
msh = array[1..392] of SmallInt;

TPmkts = ^mkts;
TPmsh = ^msh;

Pkts: array[1..Blocks, 1..RTParts] of TPmkts = ( (nil, nil),
                                (nil, nil), (nil, nil), (nil, nil) );
Psh: array[1..4, 1..2] of TPmsh = ( (nil, nil),
                                (nil, nil), (nil, nil), (nil, nil) );
...
Df: array[1..4, 1..2] of integer;

{------------------------------------------------------------------------}

function OpenA(FileName: ShortString; Mode: LongWord): integer;
begin
  Result:= FileOpen(FileName, Mode);
end;

{------------------------------------------------------------------------}

function ReadA(Df: integer; Pmas: Pointer; L: word): boolean;
begin
  Result:= false;
  if FileSeek(Df, 0, 0) = 0 then
    if FileRead(Df, Pmas^, L) > 0 then
      Result:= true;
end;
...

{------------------------------------------------------------------------}

Df[BlNum, ROTO]:= OpenA(ShifrFileName, fmShareDenyNone);

{ Выделение памяти }
New(Psh[4, 1]);

if not ReadA(Df[4, 1], Psh[4, 1], 784) then
begin
  CloseA(Df[4, 1]);
  Dispose(Psh[4, 1]);
  Exit;
end;

Pkts[4, 1]:= @Psh[4, 1]^[9];  //<---
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, то в паскале применяется методика размещения массива в памяти row-major. Очевидно в таком же виде он будет расположен в файле, если его туда запишут стандартным образом.
[image: Расположение массива 3x3 в памяти методом row-major]

По материалам http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/memory-layout-of-multi-dimensional-arrays/